# Why can't I get the right precision?

Tags: java

Here is my sqrt function. I want to output the double value with specific precision. 
But I was getting this output: "the sqrt of 0.5 is: 0.7071069999999999 " 
The odd thing is, when I was debugging, the longResult is 707107

```
public static double precision = 0.000001;

// the main sqrt function using binary search
public static double Cal(double input){
    if(input < 0) return -1;
    if(input == 0 || input == 1) return input;

    // the sqrt value shall be between 0 ~ input. we use 二分法 to search for the value;
    double min = 0;
    double max = input;
    if(input < 1) {
        min = input;
        max = 1;
    }

    double mid = 0;

    while(max - min > precision){
        mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if(mid * mid == input) return mid;
        else if(mid * mid < input) min = mid;
        else max = mid;
    }
    long longResult = (long)((max + min) / 2 / precision);
    return longResult * precision;
}

public void Test(){
    double input = 0.5;
    System.out.println(String.format("the sqrt of %s is: %s", input,Sqrt.Cal(input)));
}
```

Comment: read here http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

Comment: If you are interested in correct calculating, use BigDecimal, it also has precision, when printing method.

Comment: Thanks, I have come to a work around, use the invert value of precision to do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Because IEEE-754 double-precision floating point numbers are not perfectly precise.

Answer (score 0):

From **A Change is Gonna Come** Java Puzzlers:

> Avoid `Float` and `Double` where exact
>   answers are required

Rather use `BigDecimal`, `int`, or `long` instead

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value.